# image attribute to a temporary marker in gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am trying to add a different pin image to client side marker.
I tried 
Icon: and picture: (the same way pictures are assigned in the controller side) but non of them seem to work

```
var tempmarker = {lat: lat, lng: lng, "infowindow":"hello:, picture:"assets/pin.png"}
```

I tried to find more information in the gmaps4rails docs but could not find any list of attributes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample of expected json:

```
{
"lat":50.8503396,
"lng":4.3517103,
"picture":
  {
   "url":"/logo.png",
   "width":32,
   "height":32
  },
"infowindow":"Bar"
}
```

[Source code is pretty clear.](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/google/builders/marker.coffee#L6)

Comment: Thank you, but doing     var tempmarker = {lat: lat, lng: lng,"picture":{"url": "assets/pin.png"}, "infowindow":infoWindowContent};

results in the following error Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. 

do i need to add an ajax call if I am trying to access a picture from my rails assets folder ?

Comment: but you should pass width and height

Comment: BTW your gem is amazing I love it so much :). Just a bit hard for a noob.

Comment: I encourage you to read the source. Its pretty well documented (for builders), or self explanatory, for objects